# Session storage counter

Tags: javascript, html, session, counter, session-storage

I would like to make a simple counter script, which assign a number value for a text value (e.g. good - 1, moderate - 2, excelent - 3), after i would like to store that value in the session storage and after a page reload, i would like to continue the counting from the previous result value.

I have the counter script, and the HTML but I couldn't restore the previous value and continue the counting. Here is the script:

```
function modify_qty(val) {
    var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
    var new_qty = parseInt(qty,10) + val;

    if (new_qty < 0) {
        new_qty = 0; document.getElementById('qty').value = new_qty;
        document.getElementById("result").value = sessionStorage.getItem("qty");
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("qty");
    }

    document.getElementById('qty').value = new_qty;
    return new_qty; 
}
```

I use the following html:

```
    <table id="main">

            <tr>
                <td><button id="up" onclick="modify_qty(1)">Poor</button> </td>
                <td><button id="up" onclick="modify_qty(2)">Moderate</button></td> 
                <td><button id="up" onclick="modify_qty(3)">Good</button></td>
                <td><button value="Refresh Page" onClick="  sessionStorage.qty = qty.value; window.location.reload();">Reload</button></td>
                <td><button value="Clear" onClick="sessionStorage.clear (result);window.location.reload();">Clear</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

        <div class="box">    
                <input id="qty" type="text" value="0" />
                <input id="result" value="0"/>
```

So basically I would like to Select the Moderate (2) button it will give 2 "points" to the session storage, and after I refresh the page, the counter will show "2" and I would hit the Good (3) button and after the second refresh the counter should show "5". Its a little bit complicated but I got stuck.

Any idea?

Comment: I think you know what is session storage and how to use it. So basically whenever you update a value which you want to use in future keep that in session storage on some key. And retrieve that whenever you want on the browser same tab only.

Comment: You are not saving anything in the `sessionStorage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, this has a script error when posting it via Stack Overflow's Code Snippet so I used JSFiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/kqexbhmo/

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Example</h3>

  <div data-score="1">good</div>
  <div data-score="2">moderate</div>
  <div data-score="3">excellent</div>
  <div id="reset">reset</div>
  <div id="score"></div>
</div>



var votes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-score]');
for (var ix = 0; ix < votes.length; ix++) {
  votes.item(ix).addEventListener('click', function() {
    localStorage.setItem('score', getScore() + parseInt(this.dataset.score, 10));
    showScore();
  });
}

document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', function() {
  localStorage.removeItem('score');
  showScore();
});

function getScore() {
  return parseInt(localStorage.getItem('score') || 0, 10);
}

function showScore() {
  document.getElementById('score').innerText = getScore();
}

showScore();
```